# C# How to Build an Expression<Func<T, U>> for each Property of an Object?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class `FormBuilder<TObject>` which has a method `Property<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression)`. In the constructor I would like to invoke the method after getting all of the properties of `TObject`. How can I go about doing that? The code I have now, adapted from other SO answers, just throws errors, and I'm not sure how to resolve them. This is what I have so far:

```
public abstract class FormBuilder<TObject> :
    FormBuilder {
    public FormBuilder() {
        //  REPLICATE: Property(p => p.NAME);

        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Property");
        var properties = typeof(TObject).GetProperties();

        var objectType = typeof(TObject);

        foreach (var p in properties) {
            var propertyType = p.GetType();

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(propertyType, "p");
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, p.Name);
            var @delegate = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(objectType, propertyType);

            //  throws: ParameterExpression of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo'
            //  cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'UserQuery+Command'
            var expression = Expression.Lambda(@delegate, property, new[] { parameter });

            //  method.MakeGenericMethod(parameter).Invoke(this, new[] { property });
        }
    }

    public FormPropertyBuilder<TProperty> Property<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression) {
        var member = (expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member;
        var builder = new FormPropertyBuilder<TProperty>(member.Name);

        Properties.Add(builder);

        return builder;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public sealed class CommandFormBuilder :
    FormBuilder<Command> {
    public CommandFormBuilder() {
        Property(
            p => p.SourceOfLoss).HasLabel("Source of Loss");
    }
}
```

This is how I would normally invoke the method, but I need to invoke it immediately upon construction for each property.

My end goal is to simply seed all the properties through the method, and do further configuration on them later on if necessary. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Show the actual expressions you are trying to build. would help in knowing what to use to construct them

Comment: I had it commented in at the top, but I need something like `Property(p => p.NAME)`.

Comment: I saw that but that is just a single method with no context to how it will be invoked.

Comment: I've updated my question to show how I would normally invoke the method. Ultimately this is part of a fluent api I'm trying to create, I just want to seed all the properties first. Thinking on it, you might have wanted to see the method itself, so I've added it in.

Comment: May I ask what your ultimate goal is? I see that you say that you want to seed the properties with initial values...what is the source of those values? Maybe you can use something like AutoMapper to polulate those?

Comment: This feels like an an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Given the `Property` method's body all you really want is the property name which you don't need the expression for

Comment: @Nkosi, when I read your XY comment, my first thought was "wtf?", but after thinking on it more, and looking at the `FormPropertyBuilder<TProperty>` class (not listed), you might be right. Thinking on it, it may not need to be generic at all. I'm gonna have to rethink how I'm approaching this, I think I've lost myself a bit in  generics. BRB. @Dennis, I'm not looking for the values of the properties at this point, I'm looking to build a configuration for each property so AutoMapper wouldn't really help  me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm back!

After @Nkosi's last comment, I went back to the drawing board and started from scratch. I was getting too hung up on generics, and once I pulled back a bit, I figured out how to get what I wanted. Can't say it's the most proper way, but it seems to be working now that I've applied it across my entire app. I ended up making multiple builders (template builders?) for specific tasks such as a form, a table, a PDF document. Here's what I came up with. I'll only showcase the form builder since it pretty much repeats for all other builders with the exceptions of specialized methods for their scenarios. This is the current version after several iterations since I posted my question. Oh, the project this is built for is in VS 2013 on C# 5, so improvements can probably be made once it's upgraded to newer versions.

**Actions**

```
public interface IFormActionBuilder {
    IFormActionBuilder HasFormId(
        string formId);

    IFormActionBuilder HasLabel(
        string label);

    IFormActionBuilder IsDefault();

    IFormActionBuilder IsFileUpload();
}

public interface IFormActionMetadata {
    string Controller { get; }
    bool Default { get; }
    string FormId { get; }
    string Enctype { get; }
    string Label { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

**Groups**

```
public interface IFormGroupBuilder {
    IFormGroupBuilder HasOrder(
        short order);
}

public interface IFormGroupMetadata {
    string Label { get; }
    short Order { get; }
}
```

**Properties**

```
public interface IFormPropertyBuilder {
    IFormPropertyBuilder HasFormat(
        string format);

    IFormPropertyBuilder HasLabel(
        string label);

    IFormPropertyBuilder HasOrder(
        short order);

    IFormPropertyBuilder HasType(
        FormFieldType type);

    IFormPropertyBuilder InGroup(
        string group);

    IFormPropertyBuilder IsHidden();

    IFormPropertyBuilder IsReadOnly();

    IFormPropertyBuilder IsRequired();
}

public interface IFormPropertyMetadata {
    string Format { get; }
    string Group { get; }
    bool IsIgnored { get; set; }
    string Label { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    short Order { get; }
    bool Required { get; }
    FormFieldType Type { get; }
}
```

Technically, the actions, groups, and properties interfaces can be merged into one, but I chose to split them out into methods and properties to keep the intellisense uncluttered when working with them during configuration and when extracting out metadata.

**Builder**

```
public interface IFormMetadata {
    IList<IFormActionMetadata> ActionMetadatas { get; }
    IList<IFormGroupMetadata> GroupMetadatas { get; }
    IList<IFormPropertyMetadata> PropertyMetadatas { get; }
}

public abstract class FormBuilder<TObject> :
    IFormMetadata {
    public IList<IFormActionMetadata> ActionMetadatas { get; private set; }
    public IList<IFormGroupMetadata> GroupMetadatas { get; private set; }
    public IList<IFormPropertyMetadata> PropertyMetadatas { get; private set; }

    protected FormBuilder() {
        ActionMetadatas = new List<IFormActionMetadata>();
        GroupMetadatas = new List<IFormGroupMetadata> {
            new GroupBuilder()
        };
        PropertyMetadatas = typeof(TObject).GetProperties().Select(
            p => new PropertyBuilder(p.Name)).Cast<IFormPropertyMetadata>().ToList();
    }

    public IFormActionBuilder Action<TController>(
        Expression<Action<TController>> action)
        where TController : IController {
        var method = ((MethodCallExpression)action.Body).Method;
        var controller = typeof(TController).Name.Replace("Controller", null);
        var builder = new ActionBuilder(method.Name, controller);

        ActionMetadatas.Add(builder);

        return builder;
    }

    public IFormGroupBuilder Group(
        string label) {
        var builder = new GroupBuilder(label);

        GroupMetadatas.Add(builder);

        return builder;
    }

    public void Ignore<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression) {
        var member = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member;
        var propertyMetadata = PropertyMetadatas.SingleOrDefault(
            b => b.Name == member.Name);

        if (propertyMetadata == null) {
            return;
        }

        propertyMetadata.IsIgnored = true;
    }

    protected static T Placeholder<T>() {
        return default(T);
    }

    public IFormPropertyBuilder Property<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression) {
        var member = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member;

        return PropertyMetadatas.Single(
            b => b.Name == member.Name) as IFormPropertyBuilder;
    }

    public sealed class ActionBuilder :
        IFormActionBuilder,
        IFormActionMetadata {
        public string Controller { get; private set; }
        public bool Default { get; private set; }
        public string Enctype { get; private set; }
        public string FormId { get; private set; }
        public string Label { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public ActionBuilder(
            string action,
            string controller) {
            Controller = controller;
            Enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            FormId = "panel-form";
            Label = "Save";
            Name = action;
        }

        public IFormActionBuilder HasFormId(
            string formId) {
            FormId = formId;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormActionBuilder HasLabel(
            string label) {
            Label = label;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormActionBuilder IsDefault() {
            Default = true;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormActionBuilder IsFileUpload() {
            Enctype = "multipart/form-data";

            return this;
        }
    }

    public sealed class GroupBuilder :
        IFormGroupBuilder,
        IFormGroupMetadata {
        public string Label { get; private set; }
        public short Order { get; private set; }

        public GroupBuilder() {
        }

        public GroupBuilder(
            string label) {
            Label = label;
        }

        public IFormGroupBuilder HasOrder(
            short order) {
            Order = order;

            return this;
        }
    }

    public sealed class PropertyBuilder :
        IFormPropertyBuilder,
        IFormPropertyMetadata {
        private static readonly Type StringType;

        static PropertyBuilder() {
            StringType = typeof(string);
        }

        public string Format { get; private set; }
        public string Group { get; private set; }
        public bool IsIgnored { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public short Order { get; private set; }
        public bool Required { get; private set; }
        public FormFieldType Type { get; private set; }

        public PropertyBuilder(
            string name) {
            Name = name;
            Order = short.MaxValue;
            Required = !IsNullable(name);
            Type = FormFieldType.Text;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder HasFormat(
            string format) {
            Format = format;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder HasLabel(
            string label) {
            Label = label;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder HasOrder(
            short order) {
            Order = order;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder HasType(
            FormFieldType type) {
            Type = type;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder InGroup(
            string group) {
            Group = group;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder IsHidden() {
            Type = FormFieldType.Hidden;

            return this;
        }

        private static bool IsNullable(
            string name) {
            var type = typeof(TObject).GetProperty(name).PropertyType;

            if (type == StringType) {
                return true;
            }

            return type.IsValueType
                && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder IsReadOnly() {
            Type = FormFieldType.None;

            return this;
        }

        public IFormPropertyBuilder IsRequired() {
            Required = true;

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public sealed class FormView {
    public IList<Action> Actions { get; private set; }
    public IList<FormGroup> Groups { get; private set; }

    public FormView(
        object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        }

        var type = obj.GetType();
        var builder = FormLoader.Get(type);

        if (builder == null) {
            var message = string.Format("Unable to find form builder for type: {0}", type.FullName);

            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }

        Actions = GetActions(builder);
        Groups = GetGroups(obj, builder);
    }

    private static IList<Action> GetActions(
        IFormMetadata builder) {
        return builder.ActionMetadatas.Select(
            a => new Action {
                Controller = a.Controller,
                Enctype = a.Enctype,
                FormId = a.FormId,
                IsDefault = a.Default,
                Label = a.Label,
                Name = a.Name
            }).ToList();
    }

    private static object GetFieldValue(
        object obj,
        PropertyInfo property,
        IFormPropertyMetadata propertyMetadata) {
        var value = property.GetValue(obj, null);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyMetadata.Format)) {
            return value;
        }

        return string.Format(propertyMetadata.Format, value);
    }

    private static IList<FormField> GetFields(
        object obj,
        string group,
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties,
        IList<IFormPropertyMetadata> propertyMetadatas) {
        return properties.Select(
            p => {
                var propertyMetadata = propertyMetadatas.SingleOrDefault(
                    pm =>
                        !pm.IsIgnored
                        && pm.Name == p.Name);

                if (propertyMetadata == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                return new {
                    propertyMetadata.Group,
                    propertyMetadata.Label,
                    propertyMetadata.Name,
                    propertyMetadata.Order,
                    propertyMetadata.Required,
                    propertyMetadata.Type,
                    Value = GetFieldValue(obj, p, propertyMetadata)
                };
            }).Where(
            a =>
                a != null
                && a.Group == group).OrderBy(
            a => a.Order).Select(
            a => new FormField {
                IsRequired = a.Required,
                Label = a.Label,
                Name = a.Name,
                Type = a.Type,
                Value = a.Value
            }).ToList();
    }

    private static IList<FormGroup> GetGroups(
        object obj,
        IFormMetadata builder) {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        return builder.GroupMetadatas.Select(
            g => new {
                g.Label,
                g.Order,
                Fields = GetFields(obj, g.Label, properties, builder.PropertyMetadatas)
            }).OrderBy(
            a => a.Order).Select(
            a => new FormGroup {
                Label = a.Label,
                Fields = a.Fields
            }).ToList();
    }

    public sealed class Action {
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string Enctype { get; set; }
        public string FormId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Loader**

```
public static class FormLoader {
    private static IDictionary<Type, Builder> _builders;

    public static IFormMetadata Get<TObject>() {
        return Get(typeof(TObject));
    }

    public static IFormMetadata Get(
        Type type) {
        var builder = _builders[type];

        if (builder.Instance == null) {
            builder.Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(builder.Type) as IFormMetadata;
        }

        return builder.Instance;
    }

    public static void Initialize() {
        Initialize(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    public static void Initialize(
        params Assembly[] assemblies) {
        var type = typeof(FormBuilder<>);

        _builders = assemblies.SelectMany(
            a => a.GetTypes()).Where(
            t =>
                !t.IsAbstract
                && !t.IsInterface
                && t.BaseType != null
                && t.BaseType.IsGenericType
                && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type).Select(
            t => new {
                ObjectType = t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                BuilderType = t
            }).ToDictionary(
            k => k.ObjectType,
            v => new Builder {
                Type = v.BuilderType
            });
    }

    private sealed class Builder {
        public IFormMetadata Instance { get; set; }
        public Type Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The loader I'm not too happy about. It works, but I have a loader for each builder type, so I'm just repeating a lot. I spent a few hours the other day trying to merge them all into one, but didn't get anywhere and reverted back. The main difference between all is that they change the interfaces. If anyone has suggestions on improving the loader, and/or any of the other code I'd be glad to hear them.

I do have a special case for two builders where they need to inherit the builder for a base object so they have an `IncludeBase<TObjectBase>` method. I'm not overly confident about it, but it works.

```
public void IncludeBase<TObjectBase>() {
    var baseBuilder = DocumentLoader.Get<TObjectBase>();

    if (baseBuilder == null) {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var basePropertyMetadata in baseBuilder.PropertyMetadatas) {
        var propertyMetadata = PropertyMetadatas.SingleOrDefault(
            pm => pm.Name == basePropertyMetadata.Name);

        if (propertyMetadata == null) {
            continue;
        }

        propertyMetadata = basePropertyMetadata;
    }
}
```

And that's about it. Thanks for reading if you got this far down, and I want to thank @Nkosi for snapping me out of the trap I had gotten myself into.